# How can I indent verbatim blocks?

Tags: verbatim

I have blocks surrounded by `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}`. I'd like to indent these about half an inch. I'm using pandoc to write pdfs via XeLaTeX and the default.latex pandoc template, so I'd like not to create a new environment, but to revise the behavior of verbatim in default.latex so that it is indented a little.

Comment: My first guess would be to put every verbatim into a minipage, but that is hard to decide without a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The package `fancyvrb` has the enhanced `Verbatim` environment, and the key `xleftmargin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent A non-verbatim line
\begin{Verbatim}[xleftmargin=.5in]
Some verbatim
lines
\end{Verbatim}
\noindent Another line
\end{document}
```

[image]

Moreover, you can redefine the standard `verbatim` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=.5in}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent A non-verbatim line
\begin{verbatim}
Some verbatim
lines
\end{verbatim}
\noindent Another line
\end{document}
```

This gives the same result as above

Answer (score 9):

The `verbatim` package has an internal interface that allows one to do this. One has to redefine `\verbatim@processline`, adding an `\hspace` command at its start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newlength\myverbindent 
\setlength\myverbindent{1in} % change this to change indentation
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@processline{%
  \hspace{\myverbindent}\the\verbatim@line\par}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\noindent Unindented text followed by 1 inch indented verbatim:
\begin{verbatim}
verbatim \stuff
\and more stuff
\end{verbatim}

\setlength\myverbindent{.5in}
\noindent Unindented text followed by .5 inch indented verbatim:
\begin{verbatim}
verbatim \stuff
\and more stuff
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 7):

`verbatim` like most LaTeX display environments is a `list` environment, and one of the main reasons for that is so that they do the right thing when nested in other display environment such as `quote` (or a similar custom environment with different indentation).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

X\dotfill X\\
X\dotfill X
\begin{verbatim}
%
 $$
  @@@
   ####
\end{verbatim}
X\dotfill X
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
%
 $$
  @@@
   ####
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
X\dotfill X


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as your verbatim block doesn't span a page break, you can use the `verbatimbox` package.  The `verbbox` environment puts the verbatim into a box that can be recalled with `\theverbbox`.  The `[t]` option makes sure the box is strutted, to give the proper vertical spacing from the previous line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent Unindented text

\begin{verbbox}
This is
\verbatim text
\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox[t]

\noindent Unindented text
\end{document}
```

[image]