# Indent content of verbatim / lstlisting environment relative to containing environment

Tags: listings, indentation, verbatim

I want the content of `\verbatim` to be indented relative to the actual indent of `\verbatim`, not the exact number of spaces.

For example, I like to indent at sections to make the LaTeX source more readable:

```
\section{a}
  Regular paragraph.
  \begin{verbatim}
  Gets indented by 2 spaces. Bad!
  \end{verbatim}
```

The problem is that the verbatim will also get an unwanted 2 space indent in that case.

I could solve it via:

```
\section{a}
  Regular paragraph.
  \begin{verbatim}
Not indented in output, GOOD. But LaTeX source is ugly. BAD!
  \end{verbatim}
```

or:

```
\section{a}
  Regular paragraph.
\begin{verbatim}
Not indented in output, GOOD. but LaTeX source is ugly.
\end{verbatim}
```

but then I'd lose all my LaTeX source indentation.

Is there a way to only count spaces relative to the indent of the `verbatim` environment?

If this were possible, I would expect:

```
\section{a}
  Regular paragraph.
  \begin{verbatim}
Gets indented. Bad!
  \end{verbatim}
```

to either render without indentation, or with negative indentation, but it does not matter since I don't intend to ever use it.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148407/how-can-i-indent-verbatim-blocks

Comment: @Jubobs I think that question is mostly about automatically indenting all the verbatim outputs.

Comment: Yes, it's only vaguely related; definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: I'd simply not indent all contents; my scheme is `<blank line><blank line>\section{Title}<blank line>` that, together with syntax coloring makes section titles recognizable.

Comment: egreg is right. You quickly run past the 79th column, especially if you insist on indenting further at each lower-level sectioning command...

Comment: @Jubobs does LaTeX forbid long lines, or is it just a matter of style?

Comment: @cirosantilli It's just a matter of style. Who likes to scroll horizontally? Not I! `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `verbatim` environment is not sophisticated enough for what you're asking. What you can do instead is

- use an `lstlisting` environment (from the `listings` package) in conjunction with the `autogobble` option (from the `lstautogobble` package),
- set the basic style to typewriter font,
- pass `fullflexible` to the `columns` key (more details in 2.10 in the `listings` manual),
- set `keepspaces` to `true`, which tells the package not to drop spaces to fix column alignment and always converts tabulators to spaces (see subsection 4.13).

so as to mimick verbatim output but automatically remove the leading white space. For convenience, you can even define a custom environment with `listings`' `\lstnewenvironment` macro. See below.

**Side note**: if you really insist on using a verbatim environment, you probably shouldn't leave a newline character just before `\end{verbatim}`; otherwise, that newline char will be printed *verbatim* and you'll get an (undesirable?) linebreak. For instance, you should write

```
\begin{verbatim}
    Regular paragraph.\end{verbatim}
```

instead of

```
\begin{verbatim}
    Regular paragraph.
\end{verbatim}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\lstnewenvironment{lstverbatim}[1][]{
  \lstset
  {
    autogobble,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    breaklines=true,
    keepspaces=true,
  }
}{}

\begin{document}
\section{a}
    \begin{verbatim}
        Regular paragraph\end{verbatim}
\section{b}
    \begin{lstverbatim}
        Regular paragraph
    \end{lstverbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the ability to pass optional arguments to the macros of the `verbatimbox` package in order to condition the verbatim in various ways (typically font size and style).  But in this case, I condition it with a negative `\hspace` equal to the number of `\texttt` letters of the desired source-indent, which is passed as a mandatory argument to the newly created `indentedverb` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\newenvironment{indentedverb}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\texttt{x}}%
  \verbnobox[\hspace{-#1\wd0}]
}{\endverbnobox\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\section{My Section}
  text
  \begin{indentedverb}{2}
  \verbatim text
  This is a test
  \end{indentedverb}
  More text
    \begin{indentedverb}{4}
    \verbatim text
    with a four character source indent
    \end{indentedverb}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel this is not very satisfactory in comparison to Jubobs answer, as it requires users to count a lot of spaces, and changing indentation would be a messy job.