# Large table in "programming" type font

Tags: listings, verbatim

In my code below, the table appears in a "programming" type font.  If I have a larger table (like say in a text file), how can I import that table into my document without having to typing the whole table back into the document?  Will the listing package be able to accomplish this?  If so, how do I implement this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
I wanted the contents of the table to appear in a ``programming'' type font:
\begin{verbatim}
---------+
10 1 2 4
20 2 3 5
30 3 4 6
40 4 5 7
---------+
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\verbatiminput{}`?

Comment: Use `\lstinputlisting`. If you want to mimic the style of the `verbatim` environment, see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164993/indent-content-of-verbatim-lstlisting-environment-relative-to-containing-envir/164999#164999).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `listings` is a good idea. Here's a way to do it:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{table.txt}
\end{document}
```

If you want to customize it further (e.g. adding line numbers), check out [the list of settings.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Settings)